# attr_encrypted and encrypting dates generated by the date_select form helper

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, attr-encrypted

I'm new to rails and I am using Rails 4 and the `attr_encrypted` gem to encrypt some fields (SSN, names, date of birth, etc ) which will all be inserted into the database in `varchar` columns. In the form view, I'm using `date_select` to generate the date of birth field (dob), but I am having trouble trying to convert the selected date into a string so that `attr_encrypted` can encrypt it for insertion into the database.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label :dob %><br>
<%= f.date_select :dob,  { start_year: 1900, :order => [ :month, :day, :year ] , prompt: true, add_month_numbers: true, use_two_digit_numbers: true } %>
```

The error given is a mass assignment error, but I don't know how/where (the controller/model) to convert the hash into a string so that the `attr_encrypted` gem will be able to encrypt it. What's the best way to accomplish  this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that attr_encrypted breaks Rails' automatic composition of dates from `date_select`.  The simplest solution I found was to assemble the date string myself and rewrite the `params` hash.  In your controller:

```
protected    

def compose_date(attributes, property)
  # if the date is already composed, don't try to compose it
  return unless attributes[property].nil?

  keys, values = [], []

  # find the keys representing the components of the date
  attributes.each_key {|k| keys << k if k.start_with?(property) }

  # assemble the date components in the right order and write to the params
  keys.sort.each { |k| values << attributes[k]; attributes.delete(k); }
  attributes[property] = values.join("-") unless values.empty?
end
```

Then you can proceed as normal and everything will be fine:

```
def create
  compose_date(params[:client], "dob")

  @client = Client.new(params[:client])
  ...
end
```

**EDIT:** I forgot this at first but I had to do some extra work to get the date to store properly in the database.  The attr_encrypted gem always wants to store strings, so if your data is not a string then you'll want to show it how to marshal it.

I created a module to handle data encryption:

```
module ClientDataEncryption
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      attr_encrypted :ssn, :key => "my_ssn_key"
      attr_encrypted :first_name, :last_name, :key => "my_name_key"
      attr_encrypted :dob, :key => "my_dob_key",
                     :marshal => true, :marshaler => DateMarshaler
    end
  end

  class DateMarshaler
    def self.dump(date)
      # if our "date" is already a string, don't try to convert it
      date.is_a?(String) ? date : date.to_s(:db)
    end

    def self.load(date_string)
      Date.parse(date_string)
    end
  end
end
```

Then included it in my Client model.

Comment: Sorry that I took so long to reply, but thank you so much! It works perfectly. I have been trying to figure this out for close to a week. Only thing I had left to do was date parse the string back into a date when I edit a client and that's it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a loan application form and was running into the same issue with `attr_encrypted` on my `Owner` model's `date_of_birth` attribute which led me here. I found Wally Altman's solution to be almost perfect with a few changes necessary to use in my application:

- Using this in a nested form
- Strong parameters
- Multiple model instances

I copied the `DateMarshaler` and the `compose_date()` method in verbatim, then in my controller I added a loop that goes through all the `Owner` objects we're editing here.

```
def resource_params
  params[:loan_application][:owners_attributes].each do |owner| 
    compose_date(owner[1], 'date_of_birth')
    # If there were more fields that needed this I'd put them here
  end
  params.require(:loan_application).permit(:owners_attributes =>
    [ # Regular strong params stuff here ])
end
```

It worked like a charm on any number of nested models!